# On equivalence of two definitions of Rad I

Tags: abstract-algebra

Following is theorem 2.6 page 379 Hungerford's Algebra book:

[image]

I have two questions regarding the first two sentences of the proof.

1- For $Rad I = R$ case, how $Rad I \subset {\{ r \in R | r^n \in I }\}$ is concluded?

2- Why do we need to separate the argument for two cases when $Rad I$ equals and not equals to $R$? That is, why, for the argument come after the first line of the proof, do we require $Rad I \ne R$?

Rad I is defined as the intersection of all prime ideals P which contain I.

Comment: You didn't provide 2 definitions.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжев edited thanks

Answer (score 0):

1- In the first three lines you are trying to prove that $ {\{ r \in R | r^n \in I }\}\subseteq Rad (I)$, not the other inclusion.
In case $Rad (I)=R$ this is trivial.

2- The existence of $P$.

Comment: Your solution is totally unclear. How the inclusion in question 1 holds? And for question 2, how Rad I \ne R implies existence of P?

Comment: For the first$ {\{ r \in R | r^n \in I }\}\subseteq R=Rad (I)$.  For the second, being $Rad(I)$ the intersection of all prime ideals containing $I$, and being $Rad(I)\neq R$, there must exist such $P$.